# PHP how to add more file security than authorization?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

I have an authorization system in PHP, where accounts with a certain security clearance can upload and download files. In the files directory, there is a .htaccess with a deny from all, and disabling PHP.

The security clearance is simply a entry in MySQL. How secure is this? And How can I add more security?

Comment: There's not really any general answer that can be given to this question. If you have user authorizations in the database and the app actually abides by those authorizations, the app is secure.

Comment: That depends on how you implement it.

Comment: It seems to be secure, but if someone got the mysql password and a link...they would have full access. I need to make sure the mysql password is extemely secure, probably 255 chars.

Comment: would SSL be worth using if that was an option? this way it would be much harder to get a password over an unsecured wifi network

Comment: How would anyone get your MySQL password over wifi? You're not exposing it in the web site, are you?

Comment: account password that you type in to log in. If someone had a high security clearance, that pass is valuable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you implemented it correctly, it is as secure as you're going to need it to be.

If you want to make the password more secure you can do two passwords each of 255 characters. It will be incredibly close to impossible to crack by brute force.

Another thing you can do is record information about when somebody tries more than say, 30 passwords without getting it right, and block their ip and store a cookie that tells you they are trying to hack and which account they were tryin to access

Comment: good ideas! Ill do some more research on the speed on brute forcing, and require appropiate passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the files outside of the root directory, then create a script that copies the requested file into a temp directory and removes it after the download is completed. This way, even if the htaccess would not work or got disabled somehow (can't imagine how), you're files would not be accessible if someone got the link. Good luck!